# Does the following equation have a positive integer solutions for $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods, integers

> Q. Does the following equation have a positive integer solutions for $p$? If
>   are unable to obtain an answer for $p$, explain why this is the case. If
>   you are able to find one case where the equation works, explain what
>   steps you took or any prior knowledge that helped you achieve what $p$
>   was.
>
> Note: You would need to find $r$ and $s$ to find $p$. $r$ and $s$ are also positive integers.
>
> $$9(9r^2s^2-1s^2-1r^2)=p^2 $$

So my professor gave us the above question and I am having some difficulties. I just rewrote it a bit differently (without the 1's) they were getting too distracting.

$$9(9r^2s^2-s^2-r^2)=p^2 $$

I feel like the best way to approach this problem is trial and error. I started with the smallest case: $r,s,p=1$ and i get $p=\sqrt{63}$ so that is not a solution.

I then tried $r,s=2,2$ and i get $p$ to be $\sqrt{1224}$

So there must be some trick to this problem but I just don't see it. Does anyone see how to answer this question?

Comment: The best approach is *never* trial and error.

Comment: @fleablood how about the best approach is trial and error when you have no options left :D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as
$$(9r^2-1)(9s^2-1)=1+p^2.$$
Note neither $r$ nor $s$ can be odd. For $9r^2-1\equiv r^2-1 \pmod 8$, and if $r$ is odd, then $r^2-1\equiv 0\pmod{8}$. But $p^2+1$ cannot be congruent to $0$ modulo $8$.

So $r$ and $s$ are even. It follows that $9r^2-1\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. However, no divisor greater than $1$ of $p^2+1$ can be congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$. For if there is such a divisor, then there is a prime such divisor $q$. It follows that $p^2\equiv -1\pmod{q}$, which is impossible if $q$ is of the form $4k+3$.

We conclude that the only solution in integers has $r=s=0$. The only positive possibility for $p$ is thefore $p=1$.

Comment: how did you get  $9r^2−1≡r^2−1$

Comment: $9$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

Comment: also why use mod 8 instead of mod 4 for proving r and s cannot be odd?

Comment: No good reason. The square  of an odd number is congruent to $1$  modulo $8$, and sometimes we need that fact. But for our purposes it is good enough to know that  the square  of an odd number is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: k would be an integer right? what i basically want to say is could k be 0?

Comment: also for the even case, wouldn't $p^2+1$ ended up being compared to $1$ modulo $4$ since it would be $[−1(\mod4)][−1(\mod4)]≡1(\mod4)≡1+p^2$

Comment: In the even case we used some number theory that goes a bit beyond modular calculation. To show that we cannot have $r$ (say) even, we note that if it is then $9r^2-1\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, and therefore (unless $9r^2-1=-1$) $9r^2-1$ has a prime divisor $q$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$. It follows that $q$ divides $p^2+1$, and therefore $p^2\equiv -1\pmod{q}$. But by a theorem of number theory usually proved fairly early, if $q\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ then the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{q}$ has no solution. That is at the heart of the proof that our Diophantine equation has no solution unless $p=0$.

Comment: alright but how do you know that $9r^2−1 $has a prime divisor $q$ congruent to $−1$ modulo $4$?

Comment: Recall that we saw that $r$ is even, so $9r^2-1\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. Suppose that $r\ne 0$. Then $9r^2-1\gt 1$. If **all** the prime divisors of $9r^2-1$ were congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then $9r^2-1$ would be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. For the product of any number of numbers congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ is itself congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.